# Bounding the minimum in an interval

Tags: optimization, analysis, calculus

Let $h>0$, $b>0$ be real numbers and $z\geq1$ an integer. I need to prove that for $0\leq x <1$ the minimum of the function

$$hz-\frac{x(h-(h+b)x^z)}{1-x}, $$

is attained at $0\leq x \leq \frac{h}{h+b}$.

The derivative of the expiration as a function of $x$ is

$$\frac{(h+b)(1+(1-x)z)x^z-h}{(1-x)^2}$$

Would you please help prove this? It seems simple and was checked numerically, but I have failed to prove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the claim that the minimum for any $z$ is attained at the interval $[0,h/(h+b)]$ is wrong. Constant term $hz$ doesn't affect the minimum. For any $x \in[0,1)$ we have
$$
\lim_{z\to+\infty} -\frac{x(h-(h+b)x^z)}{1-x} = h-\frac1{1-x} \equiv f_\infty(x)
$$
You can see that the function $f_\infty(x)$ is unbounded from below. Hence for any fixed positive $b$ and $h$ there probably exists such $z_0$ that for any $z > z_0$ the minimum of the considered function lies out of the interval $[0,h/(h+b)]$. For $b = h = 1$ numerical optimization gives $z_0 = 2$.

Comment: Not quite, because if $z$ goes to infinity then it does affect the objective term and what you wrote in your second sentence is incorrect. The term (of the original function) is then bounded. Am I wrong?

Comment: Note, that if $z\rightarrow \infty$ you would then prefer taking $x\rightarrow 0$

Comment: @Y.L I don't understand your first comment. Do you search for the minimizer (value of x) or the minimum (function value)? $-zh$ does not depend on $x$ and does not affect the minimizer value.

Comment: @Y.L Are $z$, $b$, $h$ also variables for minimization? I assumed that you are interested in the minimum of a function on $x$ with fixed parameters $z$, $b$, $h$.

Comment: $h$, $b$ and $z$ are parameters. But if you take $z\rightarrow\infty$ then you need to take it in the original term. I couldn't find a case where the claim is incorrect but failed to prove it